# VB: how can i copy a word next to the one that i have found?

Tags: vb.net

so, i am creating a program in VB that opem the html of a webpage, and searching the page code for a word like "youtube.com/watch?", so i want to know how i can copy in a variable the word next to the one that i looking for.
Here is an example what i am looking for:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwYv-f65P6w
so lets say that this is what i found on the page and that is what i want to copy   "v=NwYv-f65P6w" the problem is that the "youtube.com/watch?" is always the same but the next is different for any video. So how can i copy it?

Comment: So this is a Q&A site for specific problems and answers, not a tutorial service. So, please read this *carefully*: [Ask].

Comment: Take a look at the `System.Net.Uri` class.

Answer (score -1):

use regular expression to extract specific text pattern, in vb.net is so easy
 you only need is to learn how to develop you’re own pattern.
something like this.  (http://).+(?v=) this patter extract any text that’s start with http:// and contains any char and contains the text ?v=

lookup in google for some RegEx Patterns

Comment: Use the above together with the `String.IndexOf` and the `String.Substring` methods and you'll be good to go.

Comment: I've developed some scrappers using RegEx and It's works fine.

Comment: Yes, I recommended him to use your code. Sorry that I was unclear. :)